# Would accelerated universe expansion limit two photons entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, space-expansion, quantum-entanglement

Imagine two entangled long range - from very far away coming photons have lost their contact to their point of origin due to accelerated expansion of the universe, because the origin is faster than light moving away.

Have the two photons lost their entanglement?

Comment: The speed of light does not affect things, but the speed of space, I don't know if that can be answered

Comment: *because the origin is faster than light moving away* This is not a correct description of a cosmological event horizon. GR doesn't allow us to unambiguously define the velocity of cosmologically distant objects. *Have the two photons lost their entanglement?* If the entanglement exists, that fact can never be verified by observations.

Comment: @Ben , very good argued with respect to GR!
Follow up question: Are there processes in clouds, where there are typically events of two entangled photons droped in a manner we can detect the photons, because they were sent parallel near-by?

Comment: I agree it could never be verified, maybe. But if they got entangled at some spacetime point, and later the expansion of the universe separated them so they are on opposite sides of an event horizon, I see no physical effect that necessarily distentangles them. Those two regions of spacetime could remain entagled. The same thing happens with particles falling op into a BH event horizon and those getting radiated out. I understand the problem with taking an infinite amount of time to fall in, but still the cosmological problem disentanglement is similar to loosing information into a BH. No good

Answer (score 1):

Entanglement is a shorthand for " these two photons are modeled by a solution of a quantum mechanical equation" .

When you drag in the universe, you drag in gravity, and at present there is no definitive model for the quantization of gravity.This is important because the known quantum mechanical models are functions of space time, and quantization of gravity will affect space time. The answer at present is that if [flat space is assumed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor_(general_relativity)#Flat_spacetime) the entanglement will exist , because the solutions that model the entangled photons will persist.

> [We say that the universe is flat,](https://phys.org/news/2017-06-universe-flat-topology.html) and this means that parallel lines will always remain parallel. 90-degree turns behave as true 90-degree turns, and everything makes sense.

This answer does not take into account the possible quantization of gravity. AFAIK if  the two photons do not interact on the way, and one is spin one and the other spin -1 , if the source is known and one measures on earth the spin 1 photon, one knows that the other has spin -1, by construction of the quantum mechanical mathematical model. Detection of both would present a problem at cosmological distances.

> from very far away coming photons have lost their contact to their point of origin

Quantum mechanical solutions are mathematical functions and contact is not an appropriate term . The complex conjugate squared of the wave function gives the probability of the photon to be measured at an (x,y,z) at time t.That does not change,

Comment: Thank you for that answer,  it might explain to me why I don't see the phenomenon appearing often in relation to explanations of cosmological events. I wondered about that.